# Copy voxel of 3D oblique slice to 2d array

Tags: c++, graphics, dataset, computer-vision, voxel

```
for(int x = 0; x < 256; ++x){
   for(int y = 0; y < 256; y++){
        for(int z = 0; z < 256; z++){
           float zero = planeEquation(x,y,z);
             if((zero < 0.5) && (zero > -0.5)){
             pVolumeTemp[x*256 + y] = datasetRaw[x][y][z];          
           } 
        }
   }
}
```

It works only when the plane is vertical or horizontal. Sure, I'm overwriting pVolumeTemp[x,y] when there is one more z point on the plane. But I don't know how to solve it. Someone can help me?? I want 2d slice image

Comment: Try inverting your planeEquation function to take the (x,y) coordinate of the output plane as input and return the (x, y, z) coordinate of your input data set. Then, you only have to loop over the x,y coordinates of the output and copy the corresponding block from the input.